# Enable sharing Spotify listening activity on Facebook via API?

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

Is it possible to enable sharing listening activity with Facebook from the Spotify API?

[SPSession](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/blob/master/common/SPSession.h#L309) seems to have functions around scrobbling:

```
-(void)setScrobblingState:(sp_scrobbling_state)state forService:(sp_social_provider)service callback:(SPErrorableOperationCallback)block;
```

If not, is it possible to know if a user has enabled sharing to Facebook?

Edit: Thanks for the answer! Looks like there's an enum `sp_social_provider` that has a possible value `SP_SOCIAL_PROVIDER_FACEBOOK` for use with the following functions:

```
setScrobblingUserName:password:forService:callback:
setScrobblingState:forService:callback:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPSession's `fetchScrobblingStateForService:callback:` to find out if scrobbling to a particular service is enabled.

To enable scribbling if it isn't enabled, you need to call  `setScrobblingUserName:password:forService:callback:` to set credentials for the service, then `setScrobblingState:forService:callback:` to enable it.

Set the state to `SP_SCROBBLING_STATE_USE_GLOBAL_SETTING` to keep the user's global preferences in your session (which is preferred).

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm, in the case of Facebook, username would be the Facebook account email? What would I pass to `forService`?

Comment: Have a look in api.h in libspotify for definitions of all the social services and scrobbling states.